# Issue bundeling a library using webpack to be consumed in browser

Tags: node.js, webpack, bundle

Looking for on how to bundle a library using webpack, the library link is : https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/Consent-String-SDK-JS/
I tried the following structure :

```
> /dist
>   - index.html 
> /src
>   - index.js 
> package.json 
> webpack.config.js
```

content of :
**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello Webpack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var consentData = new CSLib();
        console.log('euconsent : '+consentData);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

index.js

```
require('consent-string');
```

---

webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    library: 'CSLib',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
```

### }

after runnning **npm run build** the bundle.js file is generated
but when trying to access the index file, an error is occured in the browser, say that CSlib is undefined.
please your help, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: content of : package.json
{
  "name": "webpack-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "develop": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.8.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "consent-string": "^1.2.3"
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to bind the result of `require('consent-string');` to something. I do not know the library but looking at their npm page you should be able to do the following.

```
const { ConsentString : CSLib} = require('consent-string');
```

However even if you do that it would not work due to some details of how webpack actually works. Basically each module, or rather file, is executed inside it's own scope and they do not leak to the global context. How does it do this? Allow me to demonstrate.

### Webpack internals basics

Let's start with the following example file that imports `jquery`, prints "test", and exports something.

```
const $ = require('jquery');
console.log("test");

export function test() {
    console.log("test");
}
```

Run webpack on this file and open `bundle.js`. You will find that it starts by defining a function as follows: `function(modules)`. This is webpacks bootstrap function. If you really count all the brackets you will find that it is defined and then immediately called with an array of functions with the following signature `function(module, exports, __webpack_require__)`. Each function in this array represents a module, or rather a file, that webpack has included in the bundle. You will find a module 0 which is generated by webpack. It looks like this:

```
/* 0 */
/***/function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
module.exports = __webpack_require__(1); 
/***/ }
```

All it does is call `__webpack_require__(1)`. So what does that do? `__webpack_require__` is passed in as an argument to the module function that we are in but if you look inside the bootstrap function you will find that it is defined there. It works as follows

1. If the module with the given id (the id being an index into the array of modules that we discussed earlier) has been "installed" simply return that modules exported properties. A module has been installed if it has an entry in the `installedModules` array.
2. Otherwise, define a new module object (stores the modules id, if it has been loaded yet and it's exports) then call the module function with some arguments that I will discuss later.
3. Mark the module as loaded, add the module object to `installedModules`, and return its `exports` property (we will see how `exports` is populated in a minute).

Now let's look at how webpack has transformed the code we gave it. It can be found in module 1 (which is called from module 0 remember) and looks as follows (there might be some bookkeeping stuff in there too but I will ignore it, it's there for compatibility reasons I think):

```
var $ = __webpack_require__(2);

console.log("test");

function test() {
    console.log("test");
}
exports.test = test;
```

The first line is `var $ = __webpack_require__(2);` This we have already discussed. It just imports `jquery` which is module 2 (which is why module 2 takes up most of the file as it includes all of `jquery`).

Then we have `console.log("test");`. Nothing has changed from the code we passed in.

But the function we exported has been split into two statements. First the function is defined and then it is added to `exports` as a property. The `exports` object is passed in by `__webpack_require__` and it represents the properties that the module exports. It is stored in `installedModules` in a module object. Remember that any subsequent call to `__webpack_require__` will just return the `exports` property of this module object.

**tldr**: Webpack will transform all of those fancy module based operations into calls to `__webpack_require__` for imports and assignments to `exports` for export statements. This gives the illusion that every module exists in it's own little world.

### What this means to you

Since each module is run inside it's own scope you will need to group the code that uses `require('consent-string');` with the require statement. In conclusion your `index.js` should look like this:

```
const { ConsentString : CSLib} = require('consent-string');
var consentData = new CSLib();
console.log('euconsent : '+consentData);
```